# Using facebook with my robot

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I develop a robot which is connected to the user Facebook profile. If the user receives a message, the robot tells the user to check his inbox (or it can even read the message aloud).

For that, I want to create a website where my users can register, and where they can connect their accounts with Facebook profiles. The website communicates with Facebook to receive any new information. And the robot connects to the user page on the website to get that information.

My question - is it possible to make it that way? Does the API rules allow it?

EDIT: Especially, I want to know if API rules allow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of the Realtime Update API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates).

Therefore, you need to setup an endpoint (service) with handles the push notification from the Facebook platform.

Once you did that, you can "listen" to the *inbox* connection of the *user* object. FB will tell you if something changed, but not what exactly has changed. So you need to implement an active pull of `/{user_id}/inbox` and compare the actual result to a cached past result.

Be sure to gather the "read_mailbox" permission with your app.

Comment: So, it is OK to use user website account to communicate with Facebook and then notify my robot about any updates? 
Just want to be sure that API rules allow to have such a structure.

Comment: Be sure to check FB's platform policies and decide for yourself. I'm not a lawyer